# How to remove the branch retention policy of build in Azure DevOps using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to remove using the Azure DevOps REST API the branch policy in a build retention?

The ultimate goal is to remove de build (using the API too), but since it is retained by the policy I cannot. I tried by setting the `keepForever` property of the build to false (also via API) but it maintains the value to true.

I can remove the policiy manually but I would like to automate the process eventually.

Comment: You can delete the policy via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: So sorry Leo; I am unable to revisit the question due to pressing matters. I will try to checkout ASAP. (By the way, to such a non-technical communication is this the appropriate channel?)

Comment: @Julen, Do you mean that such questions you ask are appropriate in this forum? The answer is yes, if not, there will be other members telling you where to go.

Comment: I haven’t heard from you in a few days. Have you tried the answers below?

Comment: No, I didn't. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove the branch retention policy of build in Azure DevOps using REST API

The REST API is not documented at this moment, however you can track it by tools such as Fiddler or press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome browser then select `Network`.

For example, I can use below REST API to set the `Number of runs to retain per protected branch` to `0`, so that we could remove those build retained by the policy:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{"contributionIds":["ms.vss-build-web.pipelines-retention-data-provider"],"dataProviderContext":{"properties":{"PurgeArtifacts":"29","PurgePullRequestRuns":"10","PurgeRuns":"33","runsToRetainPerProtectedBranch":"0","sourcePage":{"url":"https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectName>/_settings/settings","routeId":"ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route","routeValues":{"project":"MyTestProject","adminPivot":"settings","controller":"ContributedPage","action":"Execute","serviceHost":"c519b80d-5d71-46b3-a8e0-3edf8c026ea2 (MyCustomOrganization)"}}}}}
```

[image]

**Note:** Do not forget to replace the `<OrganizationName>` `<ProjectName>` with your OrganizationName and `ProjectName`, and also set the value for `PurgeArtifacts`, `PurgePullRequestRuns`, `PurgeRuns` and so on.

[image]

Hope this helps.